# Entity Framework - mysql stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I mapped stored procedure to my model using following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("sp_InsertAccount"))
            .Update(sp => sp.HasName("sp_UpdateAccount"))
            .Delete(sp => sp.HasName("sp_DeleteAccount"))
            );
```

but when i add record using:

```
bank.AccountsMoves.Add(entity);
```

it throws error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

the sql statement for stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_InsertAccountMove`(
IN type int(11),
IN account_id int(11),
IN accountant_id int(11),
IN amount int(11),
IN date datetime
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `bank`.`accounts_moves` 
(`type`, `account_id`, `accountant_id`, `amount`, `date`) 
VALUES (type, account_id, 
(SELECT id FROM accountant 
Where name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER() ,'@',1))
, amount, NOW());

END
```

i think that mysql stored procedure does not return the number of affected lines

I am using EF 6.0, mysql 5.7

Does anyone know how to fix this error the right way?

Comment: Why use Entity Framework at all if you're only going to be calling stored procedures?  Perhaps you should consider something lighter like Dapper

Comment: @DavidL This is a way to redirect the normal CUD statements to [stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Reading will be done by regular LINQ statements.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mysql syntax, but the sproc should return generated key value(s) of the newly inserted row (if there are any generated key values). And values of computed fields (if any).

Comment: yes the stored procedure should return number of inserted rows but it doesnt, i think mysql doesnt support it. Should I just catch the Exception?

Comment: *return number of inserted rows* - You didn't read what I wrote.

Comment: but how can i return number of inserted rows if mysql doesnt support it( i tried wrote statement "RETURN 1" but it wrote "return is not allowed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem
add to last line of sproc following line:

```
SELECT * FROM `bank`.`accounts_moves` WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: And I think it's enough to select the id only.